# how to I remove canvas white background from jqPlot metergauge chart

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, jqplot

I have been looking at the core CSS and JS library of jqplot, but I couldn't find a way to remove the white background from Canvas element (Meter gauge).

Here is the the Fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/tPf3R/1/)

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="chart4" class="plot" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         s1 = [3];

         plot4 = $.jqplot('chart4',[s1],{
             seriesDefaults: {
                 renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
                 rendererOptions: {
                     min: 0.0,
                     max: 5.0,
                     label: '3.5',
                     labelPosition: 'inside',
                     labelHeightAdjust: -8,
                     intervalOuterRadius: 70,
                     ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     intervals:[3, 4, 5],
                     intervalColors:['#d9534f', '#5bc0de', '#5cb85c'],
                     background: "#3498db",
                     ringColor: "#154172",
                     tickColor: "989898"
                 }
             }
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option called `grid` [(see documentation here)](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html), where you can set all the grid parameters - especially background in your case :

```
grid: {
 background: 'transparent' 
}
```

Please see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/tPf3R/5/)

Comment: Great, thanks. Since they mentioned in the beginning "This document is out of date" I didn't look so much into detail.